# Exclude inactive roles from getting selected by ASP identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-identity

I am trying to find out a way to exclude inactive roles from getting selected by ASP identity (Version 2.00). The Roles table in the sql server db  has a status column ('Active' and 'inactive' are the values), currently ASP identity is retrieving all roles from the table irrespective of the status. What are the options?